# Opening Terminal From Kodi (OpenELEC)

Tags: pi-2, kodi, openelec

Last Christmas I got a RPI2. I have recently started up OpenElec and need to get access to the terminal.

The reason I won't use the Rpi's offical os is because I can't enable wifi.

There is no exit option on the power menu and I have tried pressing escape on the OpenElec splash (I can't remember if it was OSMC or OpenElec)

So, how do I get access to the terminal on Kodi with RPI2?

Comment: On the main menu there should be a "power button" to the bottom left. It contains some options, one reads "Exit" which exits to the shell.

Comment: Yeah, There is no "exit" button. Just "Shutdown timer" "reboot" and "shutdown"

Comment: In this case I leave the stage for OpenElec experts...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge there is no terminal access in OpenELEC. There *is*, per Ghanima's comment above, an `Exit` option and terminal access in vanilla Kodi on Raspbian, but not in OpenELEC.

The instructions on the [OpenELEC homepage](http://wiki.openelec.tv/index.php/Ssh_commands) recommend using Putty to create an SSH session from a remote machine, with the default username `root` and the password `openelec`.

Comment: Sadly there is no "exit" button. As I said only "shutdown timer", "reboot", and "shutdown"

Comment: Yep. That's what I wrote. Plain, non-OpenELEC, Kodi *has an Exit button*. OpenELEC *doesn't have an Exit button*. You need to use SSH to access the machine remotely.

Comment: Ssh-ing doesn't fit my needs. I need a package manager to do what I want  

Comment: Unfortunately OpenELEC isn't going to work for you. It just doesn't have a terminal. You might want to take a look at [OSMC](https://osmc.tv/), which [definitely has terminal access](https://osmc.tv/wiki/general/accessing-the-command-line/).

Comment: Okay  OSMC won't work for me so I will try to figure out the wifi problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

type CTRL-ALT-F3 to bring up a terminal window.
to exit it, it's CTRL-ALT-F1 (I believe, try others if that doesnt work)

Comment: This does not work in LibreELEC/KODI in 2019.